# Android, stretching three images horizontally doesn't work on 7" devices

Tags: android, android-layout

My following piece of code is working correctly on small screen devices such as 3.7", 4" and 4.6" devices. This is footer menu that contains three images at the button screen.

When I launch the app on 7" devices all these three images align right. But those are not stretch to fill screen. they just fill half of screen and the rest is nothing.

Any comments would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:id="@+id/footerBarContainer" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tbBrowse"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_tg_browse"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:checked="false"
            android:gravity="bottom"/>

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tbHotSpot"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_tg_hotspot"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:checked="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"/>

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/tbMatches"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_tg_matches"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:checked="false"
            android:gravity="bottom"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm really weird problem. Vote up, when you resolve this, I want to know what was the problem. I would say you have different layout in layout-sw600dp, but I don't think you made that kind of mistake:)

Comment: Thanks koso, it's really strange to me as well. No, I don't have that folder since my requirement is just mobile phone. But when I install it on my tab 8.0", footer is like that. I'm sure my code is right since in Design View of Intellij Idea it shows footer stretches correctly on 7" and 10" devices. Just in real device it doesn't stretch!!!

Comment: It can be device specific, or android version specific problem. Did you tried that on different tablets? Maybe I would try remove weightSum from buttons holder.

Comment: can you please show the entire xml , or at least the one that holds this bar ? also, please do consider reading google's guidelines, as this is not the way google suggests to show tabs.here's a sample link: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html . apps that don't follow the design guidelines have less chance of getting featured on the play store.

Comment: @koso I found a solution. Please check it.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Thanks for your suggestion. I'll definitely read it. But I didn't use tab. This is my footer widget. On top of this widget I have a fragment that based on what item of widget has been selected, application loads specific fragment dynamically.

Comment: @Hesam but this is what the user sees. it doesn't matter which kind of view it is. the location matters. it's too near the navigations buttons, which is why google recommends to avoid, and it's too much like IOS which has tabs at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found solution. I'm sure above code (the code I've written in my question) is right. But have no idea why on my G.Tab 8" was not displaying well!

I added new transparent view on top of footer. Although it's not clean way but at least works on my tablet. This is new code:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/footerBarContainer">

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/tbBrowse"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_tg_browse"
                android:textOn=""
                android:textOff=""
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:checked="false"/>

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/tbHotSpot"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_tg_hotspot"
                android:textOn=""
                android:textOff=""
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:checked="true"/>

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/tbMatches"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_tg_matches"
                android:textOn=""
                android:textOff=""
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:checked="false"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot on my tablet:

[image]

Comment: since you use a background, it gets stretched. you might want to extend from ImageView in order to keep the aspect ratio of the images. : http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-platform-apps/Contacts/com/android/contacts/ui/widget/CheckableImageView.java.htm